# Company wanted to move to an advanced stage in the interview process, but hasn't responded

Tags: interviewing, applications

A company I was applying for wanted to move the third, and presumably the last, step in the hiring process. One of their interviews was 2 in 1. I replied to their request for the third interview with potential dates and haven't heard back yet.

I let them know earlier that I was also advancing in the interview process for other companies and they told me that they would try to expedite my application.

The reply was 11 days ago and I haven't heard back yet.

Should I email and ask for the status of my application?

I should mention that this is for a fairly senior role and they talked about a potential pay range and I answered within their stated range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @Egor Thank you for commenting. I don't think it's the same situation. They pointedly asked me to provide dates for the next interview. They had already decided to move forward with me. I don't know if they had other candidates they had also reached that point with.

Comment: Yes, of course. Send them a reminder, but don't hold your breath. You're obviously their plan B. You need to keep on looking. You need a plan B of your own.

Comment: I am in the same situation. You need to be patient, these things can take a while depending on the company and size. I once even followed up after three weeks to ask if this process was still ongoing. The email to me with the offer has simply gotten lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I email and ask for the status of my application?

Yes. After more than a week it's perfectly ok to ping them, especially if they agreed to "expedite" your application.

If you want to expedite even further, you can mention that your other opportunities are progressing well and it would be helpful for you to know what the time line for a decision/offer on their side would look like. Don't lie, though. Only use a phrasing that reasonably reflects what's happening.

Until you have a written offer or contract in hand: keep looking and don't turn down any other interesting opportunities.

Comment: In this specific situation, I'd also suggest calling them.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine had a similar experience once. After some days without having any news about his hiring progress, he actually pinged the company telling them as an excuse that he was very excited about this company and the current position and that he just wanted to ask if the whole process was running fine.
At the end, he got hired. They also told him that they liked his act and he is interest about their company (maybe it was a +1 reason that lead to get hired , maybe not).

Have also in mind that hiring process time varies depending on the company size as another guy mentioned above.

Good luck.